# Parsing XML string

Tags: java

I am a newbie to Java world and struggling to parse a XML string that has attributes in them.

Can anyone help me how to parse this and get all the data? My XML string can change size depending on the NumOfParams.

Below is the XML:

```
<PictureManager>
   <FuncName>DisplayImage</FuncName>
   <NumOfParams>2</NumOfParams>
   <Parameters>
      <Param type="integer">10</Param>
      <Param type="String">C://Me.jpg</Param>
   </Parameters>
</PictureManager>
```

I need to be able to get "integer" and "String" attributes also from the XML. The XML string could grow or shrink based on the <`NumOfParams`>

It will help a lot if you can post some code that actually creates a XML string with the above mentioned tags.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try to set the XML format first. No one is going to reply to your answer if they don't understand whatever you have put

Comment: You're best of using XPath for this type of XML querying.

Answer (score 1):

In java libraries exist with methods for parsing XML document. For example this :

```
    DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
    InputSource xml = new InputSource();
    xml.setCharacterStream(xmlSTring);
    Document doc = db.parse(xml);
    NodeList nodes = doc.getElementsByTagName("PictureManager");

    // iterate objects 
    for (int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); i++) {
       Element element = (Element) nodes.item(i);
       .
       .
       .
    }
```

Comment: Can you post the code inside the FOR loop? 

I am more confused as to how to get the tag attributes like type="integer" and type="string".

Comment: I dont remember documentation, just google documentation of these classes and look for methods that returning parameters and values.

Comment: @DipuKS if you want to have integer or string, you probably need to use "getAttribute" that is query by the attribute's name. Please see the answer I posted, and change getTextContent to getAttribute, you will have.

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion is starting from the basic step:

First, you probably need to think about your xml file connection: url? local?
Second, you need to instance a DocumentBuilderFactory and a builder

> DocumentBuilder dBuilder =
>   DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();

OR

> URLConnection conn = new URL(url).openConnection(); InputStream
>   inputXml = conn.getInputStream();
>
> DocumentBuilder docBuilder = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance()
>   .newDocumentBuilder(); Document xmlDoc = docBuilder.parse(inputXml);

The Next step is Parsing XML file:

> Document xmlDom = dBuilder.parse(xmlFile);

After that, it turns a xml file into DOM or Tree structure, and you have to travel a node by node to get **Attributes** or **Content**. In your case, you need to get content. Here is an example:

```
String getContent(Document doc, String tagName){
        String result = "";

        NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName(tagName);
        if(nList.getLength()>0){
            Element eElement = (Element)nList.item(0);
            String ranking = eElement.getTextContent();
            if(!"".equals(ranking)){
                result = String.valueOf(ranking);
            }

        }
        return result;
    }
```

return of the getContent(xmlDom,"NumOfParams") is "2".

After you can parse simple xml file, you could try to travel all the xml file and print it out. Then get touch with SAX or JAXB.

Good luck